# Instagram API Locations Endpoint

Tags: api, instagram, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to access the Instagram API location endpoint with the below call, but keep getting the error further below:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search/?lat=40.758895&lng=-73.985131&access_token=MY-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIError","code":400,"error_message":"Endpoint temporarily unavailable; please retry shortly"}}
```

This has been consistent for the last 12+ hours. Is the Instagram API truly this unreliable or am I missing something?
(Note: this is the lat/lon for Times Square, so I would expect locations to show up)

Comment: Have you tried here http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/? (Will do now.) Are you using `CURL` or `AJAX`?

Comment: I guess it is as a company with over 200 million users says: *It is not available; temporarily*.

Comment: AJAX. I'm using AngularJS and properly setting the callback to JSON. Just left that part out as to not complicate the question. Thanks for that link, it's definitely helpful for testing.

Comment: Yeah, but forget it. I tried in the APIGEE console, and it throws a 500. Pasted into browser address bar = same `meta` as you.

Comment: Pretty disappointing for such a large company. I'll keep trying periodically.

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps some license problems. Guess they do not own Google Maps. %)P

Comment: Me too. Same problem.

Comment: Just a heads up. I just successfully called the location search endpoint. Thankfully it looks like it's back up again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem currently affecting Instagram's API servers. First seen by my servers 20 hours ago.

[image: Sentry graph of Instagram 400 temporarily unavailable error]

Comment: Just a heads up. I just successfully called the location search endpoint. Thankfully it looks like it's back up again!

Comment: Broken again as of 2 hours ago. @MattDionis

Comment: Now I'm getting a 503 - Service Unavailable and can't even access the API documentation. Maybe building around the Instagram API wasn't a good idea on my part. @uberdog