# Instagram GET /locations/search returns 400 error

Tags: instagram

Every time I call the GET /locations/search [API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/) endpoint always returns me an error

```
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "APIError",
    "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Endpoint temporarily unavailable; please retry shortly"
  }
}
```

Examples of requests:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&client_id=CLIENT_ID
>
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?FOURSQUARE_V2_ID=4ac518b6f964a5201ea120e3&client_id=CLIENT_ID

The same response if I use an "access_token".

Obviously, I use a proper CLIENT_ID and ACCESS_TOKEN.

I've tried it with different accounts but it constantly returns 400 APIError for me.

All other API endpoints works fine for me.

Thanks.

Comment: http://downdetector.com/status/instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (all?) clients have been receiving that error on that endpoint for the past 48 hours. It's not just you.

[image: Sentry dashboard screenshot]

[See this other Stackoverflow question regarding this outage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509308/instagram-api-locations-endpoint)

Comment: is there any information from Instagram about the problem? When they are going to fix that?

Comment: Broken again as of 2 hours ago.